Visual Studio Debugger sometimes steps into System.Object.Object()
Every once in a while, when I try to step into a certain method call, the Visual Studio debugger first steps into the constructor of class Object in namespace System.
So, I have to single-step once more in order to be taken out of the Object constructor and back to the method that I was intending to step into.
This is happening despite the fact that I do, of course, have "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Debugging" -> "General" -> "Enable Just My Code" checked.
This is happening as of a few Visual Studio updates ago. (I do not think it was happening in 2023.) On the other hand, it may have something to do with me upgrading to net8.0, which I did a few months ago. I can't be sure exactly when it started happening.
Does anyone know how I can prevent this from happening?
Note: the answer "Ditch Visual Studio" would, of course, be absolutely technically correct, but impractical, due to various unfortunate reasons having to do with politics, monopolies, unscrupulous marketing practices such as vendor-lock-in, etc.

Hi, what is the version of Visual Studio you are based on? I am using 17.9.6 version, and during single-step step, I didn't notice the situation that you encouneted. If possible, could you please share a demo of this(unproduction code that can reproduce the issue)?  :)

@BowmanZhu-MSFT hello, thanks for responding. I try to always use the latest version of Visual Studio, (hoping for bugs to be resolved,) so I am using Version 17.9.7.   I cannot currently share a demo because it is part of a medium-sized (meaning: HUGE) solution. I am planning to create a small solution so that I can share it to troubleshoot various problems, but doing so is low priority, and I bet that when I do that, most problems will disappear.  I was asking the question in case someone else is experiencing the same, so we can see what we have in common.

Could you check class Object in Modules window  that shows which code modules the debugger is treating as My Code (user code), along with their symbol loading status? If you create a new project with a demo class, does debugger step  into System.Object.Object()?

@DouXu-MSFT thanks for helping.  I just got the chance to try this. The modules window shows that the debugger is treating all system DLLs as user code. Their symbol status is loaded.  The only assemblies that are not treated as user code are a couple of visual studio debugger and hot-reload DLLs.  At this point I am beginning to suspect my upgrading to net8.0.5 which I downloaded and installed outside of the Visual Studio Installer. I will try a blank project, but it may take a few more days.

I uninstalled the dotnet 8 runtime that I had installed outside of visual studio; no change. I repaired visual studio and re-installed my extensions; no change.

Update: I switched computer; in the new computer I do not have net7+ installed; problem solved.  It probably had to do with accumulated entropy in the dotnet installations.

I will post an update if anything changes when I install some more recent version of dotnet on this computer.

Since you have enabled the 'Just My Code' option and still going to the object definition, please try to clean the symbol cache in Tools -> Options:

And notice whether the symbols can be downloaded after the above settings.

I emptied my symbol cache, and I will see what happens, but I doubt that this is the problem, because in "Cache symbols in this directory:" I have entered a directory which gets purged on every reboot. I have "Microsoft Symbol Servers" and "NuGet.org Symbol Servers" both checked, and I also have "http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols" in the list, and checked, do you think this can be a problem?

@MikeNakis If you don't use that, what will happen?

I just got around to trying this.  I unchecked the "referencesource" symbol servers, I cleared the symbol cache, and I restarted Visual Studio.  The problem is still there: sometimes, when I step into a method, the debugger first steps into the constructor of System.Object.

At the same time, the debugger properly handles many other cases, as evident by messages like Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'System.MulticastDelegate.CtorClosed'.

However, the constructor it is stepping into is a "DisplayClass" constructor, and it is stepping into it while at the exact same time it is issuing a message saying Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'bla-bla-bla...<>c__DisplayClass8_0..ctor'.

I also just witnessed it stepping into an implicit operator defined by the runtime.  (Specifically, the ReadOnlySpan<char>(string? value) operator.) I do have "Step over properties and operators" unchecked, so if it was my code I would have expected it to step into this operator, but... it is certainly not my code!
